How to iterate a map to create a table in Angular?
I have a Map<String,List<Number>> like this,
[
   {"aList",[1,2,3]},
   {"bList",[4,5,6]},
   {"cList",[7,8,9]}
]

and how can I iterate this map to create a table like this,
|aList|bList|cList|
|  1  |  4  |  7  |
|  2  |  5  |  8  |
|  3  |  6  |  9  |


Please use the below code:
HTML
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let key of keys">{{ key }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
      <td *ngFor="let key of keys">{{ row[key] }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

TS:
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, transition, style, animate, query, stagger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent   {
  dataMap: Map<string, number[]> = new Map([
    ['aList', [1, 2, 3]],
    ['bList', [4, 5, 6]],
    ['cList', [7, 8, 9]]
  ]);

  keys: string[] = [];
  maxLength: number = 0;

  rows: { [key: string]: number }[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Extract keys
    this.keys = Array.from(this.dataMap.keys());

    // Find the maximum length of the lists
    this.maxLength = Math.max(...Array.from(this.dataMap.values()).map(list => list.length));

    // Create rows
    for (let i = 0; i < this.maxLength; i++) {
      const row: { [key: string]: number } = {};
      this.keys.forEach(key => {
        row[key] = this.dataMap.get(key)![i] ?? null;
      });
      this.rows.push(row);
    }
  }
}

CSS:
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}


you can also not create an auxiliar array, but it's a bit complex :)

If you don't want to create an auxiliar array, you can use method "entries" and the method "values" of the Map.
The dificult is that to create the rows you should iterate over the "value" of the first entry. This is the "strange"
    @for(fool of dataMap.values();track $index) { 
       //fool becomes [1,2,3], then [4,5,6], then [7,8,9]
       @if ($first) { 
          @for (l of fool;track $index;let i=$index) {
             //l becomes 1,2 and 3 -really we don't take care about it
             ....
          }
       }
    }
          

So you can have:
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      @for(entry of dataMap.entries();track entry[0]) {
      <th>{{entry[0]}}</th>
      }
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @for(fool of dataMap.values();track $index) { 
       @if ($first) { 
          @for (l of fool;track $index;let i=$index) {
             <tr>
               @for(keys of dataMap.keys();track $index;let j=$index) {
                 <td>{{dataMap.get(keys)![i]}}</td>
               }
            </tr>
           }
        }
     }
  </tbody>
</table>

stackblitz
